# PHP / Database Advertising Directory

Tags: php, database, cms, advertising

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

What would it cost or is there already a system with a CMS like Joomla
that would create the back-end of a website like this one:
http://www.appliance-appointment.com/

Comment: Offtopic, should probably be on the webmasters SO.

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of free CMS backends including Joomla, Drupal, Wordpress, etc. The ones I listed tend to be the most popular. These allow for easy editing of content on a webpage by non-technical users as well as creation of template pages.

Comment: Well, I'm aware of this. My question is.. is there an addon or plugin that would create the structure of a website like this? http://www.appliance-appointment.com/

Comment: Your question is also about if there is a system out there. David answered that. Regarding cost; you maybe better off going to a freelancer reverse auction and putting it out there. You'll get interesting responses.